# How To Get All post author name in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I trying to get all post author name how can I get all post author name in wordpress . can I  get all author name who write at least one post and their permalinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `wp_list_authors` would get you that. [More details in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors). By default it excludes users with no posts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list author WordPress function

```
<?php $args = array(
'orderby'       => 'name', 
'order'         => 'ASC', 
'number'        => null,
'optioncount'   => false, 
'exclude_admin' => true, 
'show_fullname' => false,
'hide_empty'    => true,
'echo'          => true,
'feed'          => [empty string], 
'feed_image'    => [empty string],
'feed_type'     => [empty string],
'style'         => 'list',
'html'          => true,
'exclude'       => [empty string],
'include'       => [empty string] ); ?> 

 <?php wp_list_authors( $args ); ?>
```

hide_empty 
(boolean) Do not display authors with 0 posts. Valid values:
1 (true) - default
0 (false)

Know more about this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors